# Find the area between the Incircle and Circumcircle for a regular polygon.

Tags: geometry, pi

[image: apo]

The Apothem $r$ and Radius $R$ of a regular polygon with $n$ sides and Side length $s$ are

$$r = \frac{s}{2} \cdot \cot \left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$$

$$R = \frac{s}{2} \cdot \csc \left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$$

The [Annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics)) area $A$ between the Circumcircle and Incircle is

\begin{align*}
A &= \pi R^2 - \pi r^2 \\
  &= \pi (R^2 - r^2) \\
  &= \pi \left( \left(\frac{s}{2} \cdot \csc \left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\right)^2 - \left(\frac{s}{2} \cdot \cot \left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\right)^2 \right) \\
  &= \frac{\pi s^2}{4} \left( \csc^2\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right) - \cot^2\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right) \right) \\
  &= \frac{\pi s^2}{4}
\end{align*}

Rearranging, $\pi$ can be defined as

$$\pi = \frac{{4A}}{{s^2}}$$

**Question**

Is that correct? It seems odd that the area is related to the side $s$ and not $n$. Also, $\pi$ can be expressed in terms of the area and sides, unless there's some circular reasoning?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. The circular reasoning comes from the area of the annulus itself, I guess?

Comment: If you rotate the half-side, it scans a circle with area $\pi(s/2)^2$

Comment: If you still have doubts, you can use [Pappus’s first centroid theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem) to verify your answer.

Comment: @YNK  I don't understand your remark : the present issue is a 2D issue only...